# append column with different row numbers using R

Tags: r

I have the following input.

```
x <- c("a","b","c")
y <- c(1,2,3)
z <- c("M","N")

df1 = data.frame(x,y)
df2 = data.frame(df1,z)
```

Output:

> Error in data.frame(df1, z) : 
>         arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2

I want the final dataframe to look like this:

```
x   y   z
a   1   M 
b   2   M 
c   3   M 
a   1   N 
b   2   N 
c   3   N
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

This operation is often called a "cross join" or a "cartesian product". You can use the `merge` function to do a cross join by setting `by = NULL`.

```
merge(df1, data.frame(z), by = NULL)
#   x y z
# 1 a 1 M
# 2 b 2 M
# 3 c 3 M
# 4 a 1 N
# 5 b 2 N
# 6 c 3 N
```

If you're a `tidyverse` fan, you can also do `tidyr::crossing(df1, z)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `expand.grid`

```
out <- expand.grid(v1 = row.names(df1), z)
cbind(df1[out$v1,], z = out['Var2'])
```

---

Or another option is create a `list` column and `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(z = list(z)) %>%
     unnest(c(z))
```

Comment: This isn't quite right--it gives a 9x4 result,  while OP want's a 6x3 result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbind` as follows to accomplish the result you want:

```
df2 = rbind(data.frame(df1,z=z[1]),data.frame(df1,z=z[2]))
```